# placeholder with CRLF don't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, placeholder

(Example and code inside) I have big textarea that's contain placeholder with CRLF. I implemented it with jquery **(because specification of html 5 denied CRLF in placeholder)**. But it didn't work in Firefox. Any suggestion how to solve this problem?

```
var placeholder = "1111 \n 2222 example.";
 $('textarea.span12').attr('placeholder', placeholder);
        $('textarea.span12').focus(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === placeholder) {
                $(this).attr('placeholder', '');
            }
        });

        $('textarea.span12').blur(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === '') {
                $(this).attr('placeholder', placeholder);
            }
        });
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/q8kuoa25/

Comment: before placeholder was adopted by all browsers there was a common trick of placing other elements behind the form control ( or over it). Should be able to find some code for that in a web search. Likely a jQuery plugin or 2 for it as well. Still browsers in use that don't support `placeholder`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The placeholder attribute**

The placeholder attribute on `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements provides a hint to the user of what can be entered in the field. **The placeholder text must not contain carriage returns or line-feeds.**

Source: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#The_placeholder_attribute)

So unfortunately I think this can not be done natively. You could however put the placeholder text in the value of the textarea. You can remove the text on focus, so it acts like a placeholder.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pdXRx/535/

Comment: I know it, but this trick solve problem.And it works in all actual browsers except FF

Comment: @AntonKozlovsky Please take a look at my example.

Comment: but it have a little bug (after inputing text placeholder become black( but i will fix it myself)